# How to avoid typing passphrase for git pull executed under www-data

Tags: git, ssh, git-pull, passphrase, ssh-agent

I stuck on the operation when I need to execute Git pull command running from PHP script. (user is added into www-data group) without passphrase typing. I found that this can be solved using command:

```
eval "$(ssh-agent)"

ssh-add
```

But this command is working only under my own user (for example george). But if i try to execute  following command under www-data in git cloned repository :

```
sudo -u george git pull
```

I always obtain following messsage

```
Enter passphrase for key '/home/george/.ssh/id_rsa':
```

Note: I add user to www-data group and to visudo users too. But i don't know, how to solve password passing or avoiding to passphrase typing.

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to achieve what you want:

1. The most "correct", in my eyes, way is:

   1. Generate a special SSH key for your `www-data` user, and make sure this key is *not* encrypted with a password — because it's this passphrase which is asked for by the SSH client to decrypt the key which is then used for authentication.
   2. Deploy that key remotely (highly depends on your setup) so that it could be used for read access.
   3. Next, you have to make this key readable by the `www-data` user, *and only that user (!),* — that is, the key file must be owned by `www-data` and has `0600` (`-rw-------`) permission bits set on it.

      There are several ways to achieve this:

      - Since the SSH client looks for the key file under the `~/.ssh` directory (that is, the `.ssh` directory under the home directory of the user), you have several options:

        - If your `www-data` user has real home directory on the file system (you could know by running `getent passwd www-data`), you could create the `.ssh` directory in there and place the key in it.
        - In your pulling script, override the `HOME` environment variable (and `export` its new value) before running `git`, so that the SSH client resolves the home directory to some other place.  The rest should be set up as described above.
      - The SSH client supports per-user configuration, where one can specify where the key should be searched for and even specify different keys for different servers. Refer to the `ssh_config(5)` manual page.
      - SSH clients typically support specifying the location of the key file on the command line.  The `OpenSSH` client binary, typically used on common Linux-and BSD-based OSes, supports the `-i` command line option (stands for "identity"). So another way to go is to write a wrapper script which just calls `ssh -i /path/to/the/key/file` and put the path to that script into the (`export`ed) environment variable `GIT_SSH` so that Git calls your script instead of just `ssh`.
2. Using `sudo` is another option (though I dislike it) but most probably the new process running with modified credentials does not inherit certain environment variables existing in your session which tell the SSH client how to contact a running instance of `ssh-agent` which has your decrypted key cached (yes, the existence of this agent is why you're only required to type your passphrase once in an interactive login session).

   So you could read up on how `ssh-agent` works and how to make `sudo` preserve the environment variables related to it when running your Git binary with modified credentials.

   I'm not exactly sure it will work as there still might be a permissions problem with accessing the Unix-domain socket (or a fifo? — I can't recall at the moment) offered by a running instance of `ssh-agent` for contacting it, so you'll need to do some research.
3. Use a program like [`sshpass`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sshpass/) to feed the password to the SSH client.

   This could be done either directly or by wrapping the SSH client itself (see above).

   Note that this approach ***stinks*** as it implies the password will be stored somewhere in a clear text in some script.  So you have to make sure this script is protected in the same way the unencrypted key would be protected in the first case.

Yet another option would be to offer access to your repository using a read-only unauthenticated protocol (`git://` or `file://` schema — whichever is applicable).  The idea is that a repository might be accessed in a number of ways, and even different URLs (with different schemas — meaning protocols) might be used for fetches and pushes for the same named remote.